# What causes review bans, and how can I prevent them from happening?

Tags: support, review-queue, review-ban

I am close to getting the "cast close/reopen votes" privilege, and I will be reviewing close and reopen votes when I receive it.  It is quite fun and interesting to look through the review queues and review stuff.  But, as I am not quite used to the close and reopen queues yet, considering I was warned by a moderator just now over robo-reiewing while looking through the queues in Politics SE.

Review bans are just like account suspensions - the duration increases with every new ban.  For example:

> - <sup>1st ban: 2 days</sup>
> - <sup>**2nd ban: 7 days**</sup>
> - 3rd ban: 30 days
> - **4th ban: 365 days**
> - ### 5th ban: Permanent

What causes review bans, and how can I prevent them from happening?

Comment: You can prevent a review ban by reviewing carefully and fairly. You mention "robo-reviewing": you can't just click through the reviews, you have to think about each one. But you're not going to get a ban just because somebody disagrees with you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty much all bans are the result of doing something that is stupid or rude. It has been known to happen, for example, that reviewers will go through and either approve or disapprove everything *regardless of merit*. In general, review bans are for consistent or repeated behaviors.

So, if reviewers take the time to carefully go through each item in the queue, read it thoroughly, think about and/or learn about the applicable policies, and take appropriate action, then they are in little danger of a review ban. Even if the reviewer makes an honest mistake then, as long as they learn from it, they probably wouldn't get banned.

Comment: Over at Stack Overflow it's very easy to get a review ban. If you go through the review queues you get a test review every so often and if you fail too many of these (two or three within a week) you get a short ban. Some of these test reviews are simple (edits with garbage), some are very difficult to spot, and I've often stumbled over them.